# Assign a value from inside a map loop to a variable outside the loop

Tags: reactjs, loops, object

I have a rather large multi-step React form for inputting ingredients to a recipe. The form is large enough that I've created a separate component for the input field so that I can reuse it instead of having 3 times as many lines of code for each step in the form. The code for this component is as follows

```
export default function IngredientInput({ ingredients, ingredientSet, flavor, toggle, setToggle }) {
var unitValues = [
    {
        title: 'tbsp',
        value: 'tbsp'
    },
    {
        title: 'tsp',
        value: 'tsp'
    },
    {
        title: 'cup',
        value: 'cup'
    }
];

return (
    <View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                maxLength={30}
                placeholder={flavor}
                onChangeText={(text) => {
                    Object.assign(ingredientSet, {item: text});
                }}
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputNumeric}
                maxLength={4}
                placeholder='0'
                onChangeText={(num) => {
                    Object.assign(ingredientSet, {amount: num});
                }}
            />       
            <Modal 
                visible={toggle} 
                transparent={true} 
                animated={'slide'} 
                onRequestClose={() => console.log('close was requested')}
            >
                <View style={{ 
                    margin: 20, 
                    padding: 20,
                    bottom: 20,
                    left: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    position: 'absolute'
                }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', marginBottom: 10}}>Select the unit type</Text>
                    { unitValues.map((value, index) => {
                        return (
                            <TouchableHighlight 
                                key={index}
                                style={{ paddingTop: 4, paddingBottom: 4, }}
                                onPress={() => {
                                    Object.assign(ingredientSet, {unit: value.value});
                                    setToggle(!toggle);
                                }}
                            >
                                <Text>{value.title}</Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        )
                    })}
                </View>
            </Modal>
            <TouchableOpacity 
                style={styles.unitButton}
                onPress={() => {
                    setToggle(!toggle)
                    Object.assign(ingredientSet, {flavor: flavor});
                    console.log(ingredientSet);
                    ingredients.push(ingredientSet);
                }} 
                title={"Unit"}
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Unit</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
)
}
```

Everything works except for the assignment of {unit: value.value} to the ingredientSet object inside of the unitValues.map loop. Upon console logging the ingredientSet object I find that all the values were properly assigned, but the unit value is entirely missing from the object as it seems to be undefined still. I don't quite understand why this isn't working. Thank you for reading.

Comment: You should use local state, context or a state library for that. But have you tried using it like „ingredientSet = Object.assign(...)“ (Since it returns a new object), or „ingredientSet.unit = ....“?

Comment: Yes I've tried assigning it like you said. The same thing happens. However I guess I haven't tried using context or a state library.

Comment: Do you need the changes to these objects to propagate to its parent? Because if not, you could copy these objects to local state and update them from there. (E.g. first line of function: „const [is, setIs] = useState(ingredientSet);“ and then update with „setIs({...is, { unit: ... })“ - but make sure to use „is“ instead of „ingredientSet“ within JSX then in order to have it being updated)

Comment: Yes I do need the changes to propogate. This component sets the values of an object and passes them to a larger parent object from a parent component.